# jQuery Child selector syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on a bit of fiddling with the console, it appears that the two are equivalent:

```
var parent = $("p");

// option 1
var children = parent.children("a");

// option 2
var children = $("a", parent);
```

Is one preferable to the other for some reason? Are they functionally different, or only syntactically?

Comment: As someone who's not too familiar with jQuery, my preference would be towards the first one simply because it's more readable/understandable.  That is, of course, assuming that they are the same functionally.

Comment: Those are not equivalent selectors.

Answer (score 3):

These are not the same thing. [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children) will only return immediate children. Option 2 is like [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), it will search the entire depth of the context tree.

Comment: Haha, you beat me. The second one is indeed like `find`. So those two WOULD be equivalent. And THEN I would prefer the option with two parameters instead of `find`. Because it makes it shorter and is still very good readable.

Comment: in that case you should probably also read this article: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

They are actually different because

```
var children = parent.children("a");
```

will only give immediate children, whereas

```
var children = $("a", parent);
```

will actually give all descendants.  The latter expression is the exact equivalent of

```
var children = parent.find("a");
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) actually says explicitly

> Internally, selector context is
>   implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to
>   $(this).find('span').

Selector context (run this selector but only within a given document, element, or jQuery object) is very useful to know about, but I would say that it is slightly less readable.

Comment: is there any difference with $("p > a") then, besides that parent is now hardcoded, instead of a variable?

Comment: @Caspar -- `$("p>a")` will select children (1st level descendants) while `$("p a")` will select all descendants.  Those are good approaches; the speed will depend in part on how specific you can be in the selector you build.  For example `$("#" +  parent.id + ">a")` would be a fast selector since it uses ID -- but it will only work if the parent element actually has an ID.

Answer (score 0):

The two options are not equivalent.  Here's why:

Option 2 uses [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) which behind the scenes is actually using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

> Internally, **selector context is
>   implemented with the .find()** method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to
>   $(this).find('span').

(emphasis mine)

The equivalent would be:

```
parent.find("a");
```

The difference between `children()` and `find()` is as follows:

> The .find() and .children() methods
>   are similar, **except that the latter
>   only travels a single level down the
>   DOM tree.**